# How to make orderBy ASC when the column is not available in that table

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

My Laravel Query

```
$items = TypeServices::whereIn('id', $serviceIdEvent)
                                 ->select('id', 'code', 'name', 'min_price', 'max_price',
                                   DB::raw('(select(priority) from priority WHERE priority.map_id = type_service.id AND priority.map_type_id = ' . $pageType . ' AND priority.occasion_id = ' . $occasionId . ') as priority'))
                                   ->orderBy(DB::raw('ISNULL(priority), priority'), 'ASC');
```

I am getting priority from another table named priority.(I also have priority column in priority table)

I am saving service table details in priority table, but when I am prioritizing some services for first time then services which has not prioritize till now is coming first in the list.

I want that those services which has not prioritize till now will come at last.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use join in this case. Then you don't need nothing else to order by:

```
$items = TypeServices::whereIn('id', $serviceIdEvent)
    ->select('id', 'code', 'name', 'min_price', 'max_price', 'priority')
    ->join('priority', function ($join) use ($pageType, $occasionId) {
        $join->on('priority.map_id', '=', 'type_service.id');
        $join->on('priority.map_type_id', '=', DB::raw($pageType));
        $join->on('priority.occasion_id', '=', DB::raw($occasionId));
    })
    ->orderBy('priority');
```